# VBA Macro in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a little problem with a macro in Access.

I have a text box where I insert a string, after that I click a button, and I need to fill a variable with that string I put in the text box.

Now the code I use is this one:

```
CF = Forms![Super Gestione Iscritti].Anagrafica![codice fiscale]
```

(I cant change the names of the text box and the form, cause I'm only editing a project that already exists.)

Where `Super Gestione iscritti` is the name of the form, `codice fiscale` is the name of the text box and `Anagrafica`... well I dont understand really what is that. It seems to be the Modules name.

Can I have some suggestions please?

The error I get is Runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Here the entire code if needed:

```vb
Public Sub Anagrafe()


CF = Forms![Gestione Iscritti].Anagrafica![Codice Fiscale]


If IsNull(CF) Then

    pippo = MsgBox("Codice Fiscale non digitato. Operazione annullata.", vbOKOnly, "ATTENZIONE")

    Exit Sub

End If

CF = UCase(Trim(CF))

If Len(CF) <> 16 Then

    pippo = MsgBox("Codice Fiscale di lunghezza errata. Operazione annullata.", vbOKOnly, "ATTENZIONE")

    Exit Sub

End If

CF4 = Mid(CF, 12, 4)

Set db = CurrentDb

Set tb = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [CODICI Comuni].Codice, [CODICI Comuni].[Comune o stato estero], [CODICI Comuni].PV FROM [CODICI Comuni] WHERE [CODICI Comuni].Codice = '" & CF4 & "'")

quanti = tb.RecordCount

If quanti = 1 Then

    tb.MoveFirst

    Forms![Super Gestione Iscritti].Anagrafica![Luogo di Nascita] = tb.Fields("Comune o stato estero") & " (" & tb.Fields("PV") & ")"

    Forms![Super Gestione Iscritti].Anagrafica![Data di nascita] = CFData(CF)

   ' Forms![Super Gestione Iscritti].Anagrafica![Sesso] = CFSex(CF)

    tb.Close

Else

    pippo = MsgBox("Il Codice Comune " & CF4 & " non è corretto. Operazione annullata.", vbOKOnly, "ATTENZIONE")

    tb.Close

    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Since this is for editing an existing project, did this line previously work or is this a line you're attempting to add?

Comment: Is it possible, that `Anagrafica` is the name of a sub form control?

Comment: @Mistella This is a line that I found in the code, I think it used to works before

Comment: @UnhandledException Can you please suggest me how cain I find it? I see that it is a "Module"

Comment: If it's a subform: [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Comment: It's a different problem, but I also need to show an alert when an user try to change data in the tables (like: Are you sure you want to edit this?)

Comment: With [Super Gestione Iscritti] in Design View, look at list of items in dropdown box on Properties Sheet. Is Anagrafica listed? Select it. What object is selected on form? Does it look like a box? If yes then it is most likely a subform container control. Are you sure this is the line that debugger stops on? What event is code in, how is CF declared? Need to provide entire procedure code. BTW, appears code is VBA, not a macro. Macros in Access are very different. If it used to work, what has changed?

Comment: For your other requirement review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.beforeupdate-event

Comment: @HansUp Thank you for the reply, when I try that command Access tell me "page", what does it means?

Comment: @June7 Thank you, when i open [Super Gestione Iscritti] in Design View I see on the Property sheet, opening the list box, that Anagrafica is a Page. I also solved the other things thanks to your link (Form.BeforeUpdate event), thanks again!

Comment: Anagrafica is a Page of a Tab control. This code could never have worked. Tab control and its Pages are irrelevant to pathing for referencing objects placed on its Pages.

Comment: @June Thanks, so, how can I fill a variable with the content of the textbox?

Comment: Assuming textbox is not in a subform, just remove `.Anagrafica`.